The watched tag icon does not appear on tags included in searches or on its own tag page
Let's assume that you are watching the bug tag. When viewing the questions page you should see something like the following (notice the watch icon in the "bug" tag):

The chat tag is not being watched, so there is no icon next to it. However, the design tag does have an icon next to it, since it's also being watched.
When we click on the bug tag, we are taken to its tag page, which includes a filtered view of questions with the bug tag:

Notice now that the watch icon no longer appears next to the bug tag. However, there is still a watch icon next to the design tag.
It appears that in a search or on a tag page, the particular tag that is being filtered for appears in the listing without the watch icon, which appears to be a bug.
This appears to be the case for any tag.

It's by design (same for ignored tags, too) - if any of the filtered tags you have matches a watched/ignored tag, the styling is not applied.

@VLAZ Yeah, but it is a bit confusing, had me stumped for a while at one point as well, until I noticed that correlation with filter.

@DanMašek the reason I know this is because I, too, once wanted to file a bug for it. But stumbled upon the explanation. I'm trying to find it now.

@VLAZ I searched for a duplicate but could not find one, I guess I did not stumble around enough.

It's not easy to find. I still haven't. IIRC, it was some question about the background (since it was from before the eye icons were added) and the explanation was that it was by design that the watched style wasn't applied.

OK, details in the announcement. There are also few other sources: Background color for questions | Favorite tags in new navigation, everything is white | Where did the yellow background of interesting tags go? | Favorite tag question highlighting not working in some cases | Stackoverflow.com favorite tags do not highlight | 'Interesting Tag' question highlighting is patchy. Finally found them by searching for [tag-watching] [status-bydesign]

@VLAZ Your links give an explanation why this happens, but that was back in the days when the tags were highlighted (and apparently orange). Now, there is an icon rather than highlighting so it is probably less obtrusive. I am wondering whether this should be a feature request rather than a bug report.

@PeterJames it's an explanation for why it happens. I don't think it unreasonable to change, though. If you filter for A or B and you only watch A, you might still want the highlighting in the result.
